wxWidgets C++で wxPanelを初期化しようとするとセグメンテーションエラーが発生する
環境:
MacOS M1チップ g++-14, wxwidgets はhomebrewで導入
内容:
wxWidgetsでwxPanelを初期化しようとするとセグメンテーションエラーが発生してしまう。
#include <wx/wx.h>

class myFrame : public wxFrame
{
public:
    myFrame();
};

class App : public wxApp
{
public:
    virtual bool OnInit();
};

myFrame::myFrame() : wxFrame(NULL, -1, "Panel")
{
    wxPanel *mypanel = new wxPanel(this); //...1
    new wxButton(mypanel, -1, "Button 1", wxPoint(20, 20));
}

IMPLEMENT_APP(App)

bool App::OnInit()
{
   myFrame *frame = new myFrame(); //...2
   frame->Show(true);
    return true;
}

以上のコードはこちらを参考にしているものです。(このページのコードをそのまま貼り付けても同じエラーが発生しました。)
エラーが出る部分まで削っていったところ、1のmyFrameクラスをnewするところが悪さしているようで、またそこから掘り下げてみると2のwxPanelをnewするところでした。
実行したコマンド:
% g++ `wx-config --cppflags` -o main *.cpp `wx-config --libs`

クラッシュレポートをどこまで載せるべきかわからないですが大切そうなところをペーストします
Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000018
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000018

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 11 Segmentation fault: 11
Terminating Process:   exc handler [3263]

VM Region Info: 0x18 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4333617128
      REGION TYPE                    START - END         [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      __TEXT                      1024dc000-1024e8000    [   48K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  /Users/USER/*/main

Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libwx_osx_cocoau_core-3.2.0.2.3.dylib          0x1032e7768 wxWidgetCocoaImpl::Embed(wxWidgetImpl*) + 20
1   libwx_osx_cocoau_core-3.2.0.2.3.dylib          0x103246990 wxWindow::SetPeer(wxWidgetImpl*) + 344
2   libwx_osx_cocoau_core-3.2.0.2.3.dylib          0x1032461cc wxWindow::Create(wxWindow*, int, wxPoint const&, wxSize const&, long, wxString const&) + 160
3   libwx_osx_cocoau_core-3.2.0.2.3.dylib          0x1033911a4 wxPanelBase::Create(wxWindow*, int, wxPoint const&, wxSize const&, long, wxString const&) + 20
4   main                                   0x1024dfc28 wxPanel::wxPanel(wxWindow*, int, wxPoint const&, wxSize const&, long, wxString const&) + 100
5   main                                   0x1024e0bcc Panel::Panel() + 136
6   main                                   0x1024e0fdc App::OnInit() + 44
7   libwx_osx_cocoau_core-3.2.0.2.3.dylib          0x10323ca08 wxApp::CallOnInit() + 152
8   libwx_baseu-3.2.0.2.3.dylib            0x102ecf768 wxEntry(int&, wchar_t**) + 80
9   main                                   0x1024e0edc main + 28
10  dyld                                   0x19aa320e0 start + 2360

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19adb5d20 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19adb5d20 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:: com.apple.NSEventThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19ad7a1f4 mach_msg2_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19ad8cb24 mach_msg2_internal + 80
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19ad82e34 mach_msg_overwrite + 476
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x19ad7a578 mach_msg + 24
4   CoreFoundation                         0x19ae9a680 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160
5   CoreFoundation                         0x19ae98f44 __CFRunLoopRun + 1208
6   CoreFoundation                         0x19ae98434 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608
7   AppKit                                 0x19e822188 _NSEventThread + 144
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19adbaf94 _pthread_start + 136
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x19adb5d34 thread_start + 8


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x000060000020ca50   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000600000f1c590   x3: 0x000000016d9231a8
    x4: 0x0000000000000001   x5: 0x0000000000001980   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x00000001032e7754   x9: 0x000000013f905260  x10: 0x0000000000000008  x11: 0x000060000020c960
   x12: 0x0000000000000007  x13: 0x0000000000000001  x14: 0x00000000000007fb  x15: 0xffff9fffffdf36a0
   x16: 0x0000000202c27f40  x17: 0x8000600002121ac4  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x000060000020ca50
   x20: 0x000060000020ca50  x21: 0x0000000103659000  x22: 0x0000000103660600  x23: 0x00000000ffffffff
   x24: 0x000000013f904c40  x25: 0x000000019aaa631b  x26: 0x0000000000000000  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x0000000000000000   fp: 0x000000016d9231f0   lr: 0x0000000103246990
    sp: 0x000000016d9231e0   pc: 0x00000001032e7768 cpsr: 0x00001000
   far: 0x0000000000000018  esr: 0x92000006 (Data Abort) byte read Translation fault


メインコードの上に#include <wx/wx.h>があります。

提示したソースコードの修正はコメントではなく記事そのものを編集して行ってください。それから参考にした記事のソースコードから変えるべきでないところを変えてしまったのでは？ クラス名にmyを付けるとか参考記事の複数のソースコードを切り貼りして混ぜ合わせてしまうのではなく、最初は参考にしたソースコードそのままでコンパイル・動作させてから、本当に変えたい部分だけを変えてみてはどうでしょう？ こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に。良い質問をするには？, 再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方

ご教授ありがとうございます！参考にしたコードに関して編集で追加させていただきます。

参考サイトのソースコードそのままでも上手くいかないのなら、参考サイトのwxWidgets インストール とかwxWidgetsのwxWidgets for macOS installation とかは正常に行われてwxWidgetsのサンプル的な何かは正常にコンパイル・動作出来ているのでしょうか？ 他には5年前の記事でこんなのがあるようですが。Mac OS 10.14 で wxWidgets 開発（その１）, Mac OS 10.14 で wxWidgets 開発（その２）

参考にしているサイトにある、wxPanelを利用しているコード以前のものは動かすことができます。なぜかwxPanelをnewしようとしたところでセグメントエラーを吐いてしまうようです。
5年前の２つの記事については参考にさせていただきます！
ありがとうございます！

wxwidgetsを触ったことないですけれども、C++ の一般的なコードとして見ると、myFrame コンストラクタの定義はかなり怪しいです。親クラスのコンストラクタ呼び出しが書かれていません。
リンク先のコードでは wxFrame を継承したクラスのコンストラクタには  : wxFrame(NULL, -1, "...") と付いていますが、質問文のコードにはないですね。

うわっこれに関しては完全に僕のミスです。間違えてwxFrame(NULL, -1....)のところを消してました...
しかしいずれにせよリンク先のコードでもエラーを吐いてしまいます。ミスが多くてごめんなさい...
